# How to set a different default User Agent in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

GeoGuessr bugs a lot using the default User Agent so I prefer using Google Chrome - macOS as the User Agent. But I need to change it every time I open it.

Is there any way to set the default User Agent that always stays the same or just set a default user agent for https://geoguessr.com?